# What pattern involves multiple objects sharing common data, which keeps a reference count?

Tags: macos, design-patterns

Suppose you have multiple objects that all need to be independent, but they all need to share a common data set, and each presents that data differently and may use different parts of that data. But each shared common datum represents one unique thing.

Example: Multiple thread objects (run loops) are running and each has its own understanding of a database table. Let's say 3 of them are accessing it at one time. The common database has a reference count for the table of 3, because there are 3 users thereof.

Example 2: An NSString object is held by multiple objects throughout a Mac OS/X program.

Probably this is a very common and mundane pattern, but which one?

Thanks.

Comment: Inheritance?... In OO languages there is the concept of a `static` variable, which sits at the class level... All object instances of that class share the same `static` variable value.

Comment: In any case, the `NSString` example you are speaking of is simply a case of several objects holding a *reference* to a single `NSString` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like model-view. The common data set is the model, and the multiple objects that present that data in different ways are the views.